# Get pandas column where two column values are equal

Tags: python, pandas

I want to subset a DataFrame by two columns in different dataframes if the values in the columns are the same. Here is an example of df1 and df2:

```
df1
    A         
0   apple
1   pear
2   orange
3   apple

df2
    B
0   apple
1   orange
2   orange
3   pear
```

I would like the output to be a subsetted df1 based upon the df2 column:

```
    A   
0   apple
2   orange
```

I tried
df1 = df1[df1.A == df2.B] but get the following error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I do not want to rename the column in either.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: So need test index values and columns `A,B` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need compare index values with both columns create `Multiindex` and use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df = df1[df1.set_index('A', append=True).index.isin(df2.set_index('B', append=True).index)]
print (df)
        A
0   apple
2  orange
```